# Which algorithms can not be parallelized?

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing

Is there any algorithm which is very difficult to parallelize or the research is still active?

I wanted to know about any algorithm or any research field in parallel computing.

Anything, I searched for, has a 'parallel' implementation done. Just want to do some study on any unexplored parallel computing field.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parallelize"? Arguably, *every* algorithm is parallelizable, just not always well. (It might be more interesting to find *new* algorithms, in any case.)

Comment: You got it right, my purpose is finding algorithms which are  difficult to parallelize. Can you tell me more about what you mean by finding new algorithms?

Comment: You did not answer my question. How many processors do you allow (5, $p$, $n$, $\infty$)? What kind of speedup and/or efficiency are you after (any speedup, speedup linear in number of processors, poly-logarithmic total time)?

Comment: As of now, i'm looking out for algorithms which are difficult to parallelize i.e exploring the field and then decide accordingly after studying them.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773937/algorithms-which-are-inherently-not-possible-to-parallelise

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is basically an open research problem relating to the [NC=?P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)) question where NC is taken as the class of efficiently parallelizable algorithms.

in an influential/broadranging survey from Berkeley ["the landscape of parallel computing"](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2006/EECS-2006-183.pdf), there are classes of algorithms or parallelism patterns separated into "dwarves". of the 1st 6 identified, it looks like $n$-body problems maybe relatively difficult to efficiently parallelize as the $n$ increases because there are $n^2$ interactions between all the $n$ points.

they added 6 others later in the paper and suggest that a last one called "FSMs" (p14) where the problem involves computing FSM like calculations (such as the $n$th state of the FSM) may be the opposite of ["embarrassingly parallel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) something they propose calling "embarrassingly sequential".

see also [are there famous algorithms in sci. comp. that cant be parallelized](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/are-there-any-famous-problems-algorithms-in-scientific-computing-that-cannot-be), scicomp.se

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the links and explanation!

Answer (score 13):

This article gives a number of problems that are easy to solve sequentially but difficult to parallelise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-complete

The **circuit value problem** ("given a Boolean circuit + its input, tell what it outputs") is a good starting point — easy to understand, easy to solve with sequential algorithms, and nobody knows if it can be parallelised efficiently.

Comment: This assumes a complexity-theoretic definition of "parallelizable" which may or may not be of interest.

Comment: @Raphael: AFAIK, many classical P-complete problems are difficult to parallelise not only in theory but also in practice (even if you have a relatively small number of processors).

Comment: @JukkaSuomela There are also cases where complexity theory suggests hardness, but things work nicely in practice. Furthermore, [positive results don't mean much in practice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/how-to-scale-down-parallel-complexity-results-to-constantly-many-cores), either.

Comment: One might want to add that, from a complexity theoretic point of view, it is not at all clear whether "inherently unparallizable" problems do even exist, by the fact that it is not known whether $\mathsf{NC} = \mathsf{P}$, as vzn does in his answer

Answer (score 9):

From a practical-oriented perspective, you are asking about inherently-sequential algorithms.  There are many candidates, such as hash-chaining, which is believed to be very difficult to parallelize.  Hash-chaining is widely used in cryptography.  For instance, the password-hashing scheme bcrypt was designed to try to make it difficult to speed up the hash through parallelization.  Another example is repeated-squaring (again, in cryptography).

Comment: I found a few papers who have parallelize hash chaining, but havent read it completely. I'll go through the same. Anyway, thanks for the input!

Comment: @TheUknown Links to those papers would be appreciated.

Comment: @m33lky Sorry, I do not have any of those papers with me now. This was way back in Jan and I finally continued my research on another topic. However, you can look up online on google scholar and I'm sure you will get many papers

Comment: On the practical perspective, it is also worth mentioning that if the algorithm is e.g. memory bound, then parallelization won't help much: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868568/what-do-the-terms-cpu-bound-and-i-o-bound-mean/33510470#33510470