# Fundamentally serial algorithm

Tags: parallel-computing

[Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) generally divides a task into "things that can be parallelized" and "things that can't".  Now, I know what "things that can be parallelized", and it's not too hard to imagine things whose parallelizations aren't obvious, but it's not clear to me what makes a task fundamentally non-parallelizable, whether such a thing is known to exist, or whether the question is even well-formed.  The best example I can think of is, say, hashing an input 100 times - but I'm not sure it's been proven there is no parallelization, or just that we haven't found one.

One conceivable outcome, if non-parallelization can't be proven - it's vaguely plausible that there could be some way of processing *arbitrary* algorithms that, at some cost of memory and/or efficiency, allows parallelization across an arbitrary number of cores.

Has it been proven there exist algorithms/tasks cannot be parallelized?  (Or the opposite?)  Have any specific algorithms been proven to be fundamentally serial?  Is there a commonly used set of definitions/rules/assumptions for talking about the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which algorithms can not be parallelized?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/which-algorithms-can-not-be-parallelized)

Comment: @Dmitry Oh, thanks; I'd say that's similar enough to close my question as a duplicate.  Briefly looking through the responses, it seems like the answer is "we're not sure yet; we're working on it."