# Suppose P = NC - what then?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, parallel-computing, polynomial-time

Suppose tomorrow someone discovered a proof that P = NC. What would the consequences for computer science research and practical applications be in this case?

Comment: Highly relevant and possibly even a duplicate: [P-Completeness and Parallel Computation](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1415/9550).

Comment: What do *you* think? What does your research of known results tell you?